# How to display Json Data in JQuery autocomplete UI?

Tags: php, jquery, json

i am using jquery autocomplete ui and i am getting data in json format like this

```
[{"organization_name":"health info"},{"organization_name":"Canada health"},{"organization_name": "org 1"}]
```

Here is my jquery code which is not displaying json data properly

```
 $('input[name=profileOrg]').autocomplete({
                    source:'CHI_custom/customScripts/getorgname.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    minLength:2

                });
```

can anyone help to how can display data bellow the auto complete textboX?

Comment: have you read the docs

Comment: you need `label: str, value: str` pairs in your JSON.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy you means like this `[{lable:organization_name,value:health info},{lable:organization_name,value:value2}]`

Comment: the source should of format [{value:'health info', label:'health info'}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the way autocomplete shows the item

```
$('input[name=profileOrg]').autocomplete({
    source:'CHI_custom/customScripts/getorgname.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    minLength:2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).val(ui.item.organization_name);
        return false;
    }
})
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
          .data("item.autocomplete", item)
          .append('<a>' + item.organization_name + '</a>')
          .appendTo(ul);
};
```

More info on the jQuery documentation: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: Thank you your code is work for me thank you very much...you are my savior

Comment: you code is work fine but when i select name from the list the name doesn't show in text box

Comment: You are right. You need to add the `select` option to the function. Answer edited.

Comment: Thanks you very much for save my time but i need to show data in select tag