# JQuery autocomplete doesnt display returned json data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I've been struggling with this since yesterday. I successfully get the data from server in Json format but the data doesnt shown in the input box. [image]
I have checked similar questions and I think it is kind of format problem like [this guy's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301135/how-to-display-json-data-in-jquery-autocomplete-ui), but I couldnt solve it out. 
I have tried many code examples and this was the least complicated one.

**HTML form**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="customerAutocomp" class="ui-autocomplete-input" />
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $("#customerAutocomp").autocomplete({
        source: "suggest_name.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui){
            var url = ui.value.id;
            if (url !== '#') {
                location.href = '/somepage.php?somecode=' + url;
            }
        },

        // optional
        html: true,

        // optional (if other layers overlap the autocomplete list)
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

**JQuery Versions** that I'm using

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js">       </script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**PHP**

```
//connnections strings//
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name) or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("stackoverflow");
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

$qstring = "SELECT fullname as value,id FROM users WHERE fullname LIKE '%".$term."%'";
$result = mysql_query($qstring);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
        $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
        $row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
        $row_set[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($row_set);
```

Comment: Why do you have js files in json response ?

Comment: oh my god. I put them in php file by accident. I deleted them and the problem solved. Thanks bro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the script files returned in the JSON response.

Hope it helps !